# Calling a lambda from Reflection-generated assembly

Tags: c#, reflection.emit

I'm creating an assembly using Reflection.Emit and I want it to invoke a special callback.

Here's a simplified version of the code:

```
public void Call(ILGenerator il, Delegate action)
{
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, action.Method);
}

public static void DoStuff()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Action invoked!");
}

Call(CurrentMethod.ILGenerator, DoStuff);
```

This code works just as expected.

However, I want to pass a lambda expression, like this:

```
Call(CurrentMethod.ILGenerator, () => Console.WriteLine("test"));
```

This time the following exception is thrown:

> System.MethodAccessException : Attempt by method '.Run()' to access method 'Compiler.Test.ImportedFunctions.b__0()' failed.

Is there a way to work around it?

Comment: Is the code running under full trust?

Comment: @Greg, the assembly is created with `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(name, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave)`. How do I check the trust settings?

Comment: @Impworks: If you can do that, you already running under full trust :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Delegate` it too generic. Try `Action`.

**BUT BE WARNED!**

If the delegate's target property is not null, this is not possible.

You could work around this by storing the value of target temporarily in static field.

Possible solution (modifiers emitted):

```
class Foo { static object target; }

public void Call(ILGenerator il, Action action)
{
    Foo.target = action.Target;
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldsfld, typeof(Foo).GetField("target");
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, action.Method);
}
```

If you run in a single threaded environment with no recursive calls, this will work.

For a recursive environment, you would need to use dynamic binding for `Foo.target`, which is not available in C#.

Luckily [I have written such a facility](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/153896/Dynamic-Binding-in-C) for C# already.

Comment: Unluckily, `Func<>` and `Action<>` objects created from lambdas are not static. I will give your facility a try.

Comment: It is only non-static if the delegate captures variables.